# Open submenu in toolbar menu when I click a button in my layout

Tags: android, menu, submenu

I have a menu with a lot of items and submenus and I would like to know if it is possible to open a submenu programmatically via click some button in the layout.

```
-menu
   -item1
   -item2
        -submenu
...
```

I want to open this "last" menu without clicking items in toolbar

I tried `menu.findItem(R.id.item1).expandActionView()` but it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved adding the next code to my click listener:

```
menu.performIdentifierAction(R.id.my_item, 0)
```